# Making value type behave like a reference type using boxing and implicit conversions

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

I would like to box a value type and give it implicit conversions. Unfortunately doing so makes it stop behaving like a reference type i.e.

```
MyTnt i1 = 3; //MyValue has a field value = 3
MyInt i2 = 5; //value = 5

i1 = i2;      //both i1 and i2 = 5
i2 = 4;       //i1 = 5, i2 = 4; should be i1 = i2 = 4;
```

Is it possible to write boxing using implicit conversions so it behaves here as expected?

Comment: Reference types behave the same way as your example.

Comment: MyInt is a wrapper for int, and it has implicit conversions. I have just tested pretty much what I've written above and I can tell you, it doesn't behave the way I said it is expected of them.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. Write a class that has nothing to do with being a wrapper over a struct. Write similar code to the above. It will behave the same way. Writing `i1 = i2;` is not permanently linking these variables. The only thing that is happening is that for a moment in time, these variables reference the same object. Assigning a different value to i2 changes that reality, and never has anything to do with i1.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for explaining, now I see what was wrong with my way of thinking.

Comment: You say it 'stops behaving like a reference type' but reference types will behave in the same way. Try replacing `MyInt` with `string` and the values `"3", "4" and "5"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're misunderstanding some points.

One thing is creating *references* to hold an object or a value type, and another story is giving an argument [*by reference*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

`i1` would also hold `4` if you would pass it by reference in some method:

```
public void X(int i2, ref MyInt i1)
{
   // When you define a ref parameter
   // you're not creating a new reference but you're
   // reusing the given one
   i1 = i2;
}

MyInt i1 = 4;
MyInt i2 = 0;     

// This would produce what you expect
X(i2, ref i1);

// Now i2 is 4
```

Comment: Ok, I see where I made a mistake. It should've been i2.value = 4 for it to behave like I expected. Then again in cpp I would've overridden the assignment operator in the right way, but seeing as there is no such possibility in C#, is there another way to make it look as "ï2 = 4" and behave as if it were "i2.value = 4"?

Comment: @wjtk4444 I'll take a look later, now I've to go to have dinner ;D

Comment: @wjtk4444 I believe that there should be no alternative for this :(

Comment: I was afraid you would say so... Well, it's not something VERY important. It just would be convenient to be able to do such things.